# Progress bars during installation

Tags: linux, installation

For long time, I have been curious about 3 overlapping progress bars during installation of Linux distributions.

I have seen people using 2 overlapping progress bars (one mostly for cache and the other for actual writes). But the 3 bars in Fedora installation always hit my mind.

Is there any specific purpose for each progress bar, or its just for fun?

Most recently, I installed Fedora 16 to try out new Gnome 3.

Three progress bars were:

1. Dull Blue, which was fastest
2. Bright Blue, behind it
3. White, at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They signify nothing.

Bear in mind you can hit the up arrow key to see what's actually going on during the boot.

else, you can remove `rhgb` from the kernel grub line.